# Measurability of a stopping time in a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Suppose you have a finite-state continuous-time inhomogeneous Markov chain with transition rate $Q(t)$. Further, let us suppose that $Q(t)$ is a piecewise continuous function of $t$. Two questions:

1. Let $H_t(i)$ be the time until the chain reaches state $1$ starting from state $i$ at time $t$. How do I argue that $H_t(i)$ is a random variable for any $t,i$?

Presumably, when one deals with these chains, there is a sigma algebra relative to which everything is measurable (or perhaps an increasing sequence of sigma-algebras?) and one needs to argue that $H_t(i)$ is measurable with respect to it.

2. How do I argue that $E[H_t(i)]$ is a Borel measurable function of $t$?

Some background: my background in probability theory is not very strong, and yet now I am writing up a report which deals in part with continuous time Markov chains. I only need to do some very basic algebraic manipulations though, but they seem to require  1. and 2. above to be justified.

Comment: For an inhomogeneous chain, shouldn't the transition kernel be a matrix-valued function of two time parameters, $P(s,t)$, i.e., with components given by $P_{ij}(s,t)=P(X_t = j \mid X_s=i)$?

Comment: In this case it's a (time)-homogeneous chain; maybe the "in" in "inhomogeneous" was just a typo?

Comment: But then the distribution of $H_t(i)$ doesn't depend on $t$?

Comment: Sorry I wrote some nonsense in the previous comment (now deleted)

Comment: ...the transition rate matrix $Q$ is a function of one parameter. Unless I am mistaken, this is the matrix such that the transition probabilities satisfy $P'(s,t) = P(s,t) Q(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to the first question: assuming the Markov process $X_s$ is right-continuous, $H_t(i)$ will be a random variable, because we can write $H_t(i)$ as a countable intersection of measurable sets:
$$\{H_t(i) < s\} = \bigcap_{\underset{\Large t \leq q< s}{q\in\Bbb Q}} \{X_q=1\}$$